# Tea bag disposal plate name

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a little plate used for disposal of a tea bag called?

I find myself in a real conundrum here. Tea drinker problems.

Typical scenario: I order a cup of tea at a diner. I'm given a cup of hot water and a teabag. Said teabag is steeped for a few minutes until the tea is just how I like it: not too thin, but not too thick.

Now, said teabag must be removed, or the tea will be too strong! A small plate or saucer is immediately needed for disposal.

Establishments are often hesitant to give out these little plates, because it adds a lot of dishwashing/waste for something they seem to think is a luxury item. So, I'm left "holding the bag" as they say... and, sadly, nowhere to put it.

I must then resort to barbaric acts, such as placing the used bag:

1. Directly on the counter, where it leaks all over.
2. On my paper placemat, where it makes a big wet spot.
3. On my teaspoon, which is just rude.
4. Wrapping it in a napkin, which promptly turns into a soppy brown mess
5. Using the paper tea bag wrapper for disposal, which really doesn't work very well.
6. Into an empty water glass, which is obscene.
7. Rock-bottom has to be eating a single-serve jelly, directly out of the packet with my teaspoon, and putting the used bag into the little empty plastic container.

Don't even *think* about putting that nasty teabag on the side of my food plate.

So I need to ask, "May I please have *a little plate for my used teabag*?

English SE, please tell me, what is the name of this little saucer thingy?

https://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst39438_specific-name-for-a-tea-bag-disposal-plate.aspx

Comment: @Decapitated Soul: I don't think that saucers are for garbage; they're for holding and placing the tea cup.

Comment: Tea bag coaster then :P (i'll delete my comment)

Comment: On sale right now on [eBay](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/203138991020?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=710-134428-41853-0&mkcid=2&itemid=203138991020&targetid=1140163971769&device=c&mktype=pla&googleloc=9045102&poi=&campaignid=12128858833&mkgroupid=117045676459&rlsatarget=pla-1140163971769&abcId=9300480&merchantid=6995734) - *Brand new Bee Happy Small Tray & **Teabag Holder*** (*their* teabag holder is shaped like a teapot, but obviously most aren't).

Comment: 'Receptacle' is correct if formal. 'Tea bag saucer' is used in the trade [[etsy.com/market/](https://www.etsy.com/market/tea_bag?original_q_to_backoff=tea_bag_receptacle)]

Comment: An establishment that has such things will probably bring them to the table when serving tea by default, without a special request. If a purpose-made teabag holder hasn't been brought to your table, chances are that they don't have them, and that the best they can do is bring you another saucer.

Comment: Used tea bag **rest**, just like for cooking utensils on top of a stove: spoon **rest**. [The tea is how you like it: thick or thin? Do you mean: weak or strong...]

Comment: Tea bag **dish** is what some call it.

Comment: When they bring the tea and cup and you see that they haven’t brought a saucer you should immediately ask the server for a saucer before they walk away.

Comment: _Tea bag disposal plate_ is the formal name.

Comment: A diner is a particularly informal place of dining where tea is served in a mug (or rather you're given a mug, a tea bag, and a pot of hot water. What do you do if you get tea at a higher end restaurant? Don't you put it in the saucer that the tea cup comes in?

Comment: Pot on window sill for tea bags - I think

Comment: People are under the impression that there is a word for everything in English - there isn't.

Comment: tea bag disposal plate will have serious tea drinkers laughing out of the tea house, I'm afraid....in any case, it's a dish, not a plate.

Comment: If you have to ask, then: *May I please have a saucer for my teabag?* Otherwise, some thingy or another will have already been brought to you, and no one needs—or need utter—a word for it. (It has no official name.)

Answer (score 1):

> [Lakeland White Porcelain] **Tea Bag Rest**  "Where do you put your tea
> bag after you’ve fished it out of your mug, or taken it out of your
> teapot so your brew doesn’t stew? On our pretty little White Porcelain
> Tea Bag Rest, of course".

Brought to you straight from the UK. [ha ha]

> [image: tea bag rest]

Also, for spoons and other utensils when cooking:

Here is a spoon rest (which I am going to buy as the one I had for 30 years broke)  from William Sonoma:

[image: William Sonoma, spoon rest]

Comment: Oh I love the teapot shaped one! That elevates it! Cute!

Comment: @Jelila I'd expect nothing less from Brit tea ware. :)

Comment: Yes, tea-ware or indeed any kind of china, is one of my enthusiasms! I collect them and I'm enjoying sharing them so much, in my cafe. Drinking tea from a beautiful translucent bone-china cup, decorated inside as well as out, is just... uplifting! A moment of beauty! (Trying to keep the little finger down!:)

Comment: I think I'm going to buy a few of those 

Comment: @Jelila Be warned, if you start a collection of 'tea bag rests' or whatever anyone else calls them you'll need a lot of wall space to display them. Each item is small but there's a near-infinite variety of them, mostly teapot-shaped.

Comment: Yes, @BoldBen, that's true! I had such fun looking through them. But I've just bought 2, for my cafe. I'll add them to the pile of beautiful and eclectic little dishes we use for serving individual portions of sauce, butter, etc. They are tiny, teapot shaped with different pink flower designs 

Answer (score 1):

Amazon has the following that meet your requirements; and perhaps more that I haven't yet seen.

Tea Bag ...

- Dish
- Tidy
- Coaster
- Holder
- Rest

Comment: I really like "Tidy." I think it captures the spirit of tea.

Comment: Bad translation, like many Brazilian sites.

Comment: @Lambie I was trying to refer, euphemistically, to Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out by FumbleFingers, in a comment, some merchants who sell such things refer to them as ***teabag holders***.

While that term is adequate in the context of a website on which it is accompanied by pictures and descriptions, it is debatable whether it would be readily understood to have this meaning in the absence of such clues; upon encountering it in isolation, some people could think that it stands for something that holds teabags before use.

Comment: This answer is posted as wiki because it merely elevates a comment by FumbleFingers into an answer. Its being posted as an answer will make it easier for future visitors to this page to compare different possible ways of referring to such objects.

Answer (score -1):

Small Sauce Plate.

If you look up 'small sauce plate' or 'small dipping plate' online, and click 'images', you'll see lots of these kinds of tiny dishes, so I think if you ask for one of those, the waiter will understand what you mean:

https://www.amazon.com/small-dipping-plates/s?k=small+dipping+plates

I don't think there is really a name for that small-plate thingy as a specific 'tea-bag plate' per se.  Instead of asking 'may I have a small plate for my tea-bag, please' which as you say, is quite annoying, I suggest you ask for 'a small sauce plate'.

An Alternate Answer.

Teapot.

A teapot is really the correct place for the teabag. How about ordering tea by the pot?

The teabag stays in the pot - and you can request extra hot water to top up, giving you even more tea, for free!

I'm English, and a lover of tea, the teapot avoids the inelegance of this 'tea-bag problem'.

I get your little plate idea, though as I say, tea is better in a pot - however I do have a tiny, shell-shaped, white porcelain plate, only about 4-5 cm across, and quite flat. Could something like that fit in your bag? Then at the end, the used tea-bag goes in the tea-cup and the shell plate is dried with a tissue and goes back in your bag. It is really, a small sauce plate. And that's what we use it for, in my cafe.

Tea-time, for English people is a peaceful little moment around the tea-pot, where we can connect with another and share what's really important to us. So that's another lovely thing about the tea-pot - to share your tea-time with a friend!

Comment: Sure, any little plate will do the trick for a used teabag. And, of course, if you are using a teapot, you generally use loose tea.

Comment: Sure, 'any little plate' will do. The question is 'what to call it'. She could ask for 'any little plate' as you suggest, but then I think she'll get a saucer. I don't use leaf tea. It's too messy and tends to make over-strong tea. I think most people use tea-bags now, even in a tea-pot.

Comment: Its better to use a dish as a plate is usually flat

Comment: What’s wrong with getting a saucer?  It you’re at a place that has special tea-bag rests then they’ll probably bring one as a matter of course.  If you’re not at such a place then you just need a place to put it and a saucer works perfectly.

Comment: @Jim "Saucer" will do for coffee drinkers and the unwashed masses. I'm looking for a formal, English term.

Comment: @kmiklas -  Ok, but do you expect someone who doesn’t work somewhere where those things are a matter of course to know what it is let alone have one available?  You’re contemplating sucking the jelly out of a jelly pack just to have a place to put it, Surely a saucer is infinitely more acceptable.  As posh as you are, ***you*** don’t even know what they’re called.

Comment: I imagine the conversation going like this:  “Would you be so kind as to bring me a flimbagaroo?  A flimbagaroo? What’s that?  It’s a little holder on which to place one’s tea bag after it’s removed from the cup.  Oh, we don’t have any of those. Would you like a saucer?

Comment: @Jim Exactly! We need a new word... I was thinking "trauceb," a portmantau of "tea," "used," "bag," "plate," and "rest." E.g., "May I please have a *trauceb*?"

Comment: @kmiklas, your question seemed to assume that there **is** a generally understood word for such things; your now saying 'we need a new word' seems to imply that the answers offered so far have led you to conclude that, in fact, there isn't one.

Comment: @Jelila **No!** the teabags must be removed from the pot, or the tea will get too strong and/or bitter.

Comment: @kmiklas -  Sorry, I was trying to solve the problem, not help you find a word.  I apologize. :-)

Comment: A saucer is too large for the job, ungainly, ungraceful and looks ugly on the table. This is why I have suggested you ask for 'a small sauce plate', because the kitchen/wait staff will understand from this term what you are asking for, and bring you what you are seeking - a tiny, but dished, plate.

Comment: If you asked one of the staff in my cafe for 'a small sauce plate', they would go to the kitchen and bring you one of about 12 tiny dishes that we have on the shelf that we use for serving single portions of butter, sauce, and indeed, now, to give to people who 'need a place for their wet teabag'. In a few days, this pile of tiny dishes will even be joined by a couple of cute, tea-pot shaped ones, specially for the purpose of. So why not give it a try? Try asking for 'a small sauce plate' and let us know how you get on.